# How are the flags of ELF sections defined?

Tags: linux, elf

Using `readelf -S` we can obtain information about all the sections of a relocatable file, However, I'm puzzled about the meaning of flg.
In elf.h from Linux kernel at [linux/elf.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/elf.h):

```
/* sh_flags */    
#define SHF_WRITE       0x1
#define SHF_ALLOC       0x2
#define SHF_EXECINSTR       0x4
#define SHF_RELA_LIVEPATCH  0x00100000
#define SHF_RO_AFTER_INIT   0x00200000
#define SHF_MASKPROC        0xf0000000
```

but I got

```
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

So how are the other flags defined?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly understanding the question, but I believe you are struggling with mapping readelf and Linux kernel definitions.

So basically readelf is userspace tool that is why it focuses on userspace elf's that can be richer with sections than lkm's (loadable kernel modules).
That is why you see more flags for modules than in kernel definitions, see here at "Section Attribute Flags": http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2003-12-17/ch4.sheader.html

From the other site, Linux implements few functionalities for lkm's that do not have sense in user space (ok maybe they may do, but they are in the kernel) and require additional Attribute Flags for sections.

So going one by one:

SHF_RELA_LIVEPATCH: means this section is not for module loader but for live-patch, if you will take a look on module.c code you can see that during loading module, loader before applying relocation (i.e. loading function to kernel space) check if this flag is set or not. If is set loader just skip this relocation.

SHF_RO_AFTER_INIT: part of "ro_after_init" feature. A security feature that after module init mark sections with this flag Read Only.

As you can see both of these flags are Linux kernel specific that is why userspace tool readelf does not understand them. But maybe it should and is a good place to write own patch to this tool ;)

BTW: followup after values of the constants, from livepatch documentation:

*"The Elf constants used to mark livepatch symbols and relocation sections were selected from OS-specific ranges according to the definitions from glibc."*

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I came here trying to find the definition for the `SHF_INFO_LINK` flag. Possibly for a similar reason to the original poster. This answered my question.